# Count my multi-index length in a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a multi-index, how do I count records of the index? More explicitly I mean X, Y being my multi- index on the example below. Let’s say I have 3 individuals in this data frame. How do I find them, As the length of the dataframe gives me total rows which is not what I want.

```
          Modules
X     Y   
1    11         A
     11         B
     11         C
2    13         A
     13         B
3    17         A
     17         B
     17         D
```

How do I count the length of this multi-index?

Comment: I am basically counting the index only.or the 'x' values; just reconfirm in this case my count should be 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
df.index.to_series().nunique()

3
```

---

**Option 2**

```
df.groupby(df.index.names).ngroups
# df.groupby(level=df.index.names).ngroups
# for pandas < 0.20 or if column name conflict

3
```

Answer (score 5):

What about:

```
len(df.groupby(level=0))
```

The advantages are a more succinct code and the fact that you can actually specify the level of the multi-index df you want to perform this operation on.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 3):

If `df` has MultiIndex, this returns the number of unique levels for each index...

```py
df.index.levshape
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.levshape.html#pandas.MultiIndex.levshape

Answer (score 3):

I think that the **most legible** (and probably quickest) way to count it is:

```
len(df.index.levels[0])
```

See that if you have a non-unique index, it will count more than once each value. So you must use:

```
len(df.index.levels[0].unique())
```

Answer (score 0):

The length of the index must be the length of the DataFrame, even if the DataFrame isn't printed to appear that way. With a two-level MultiIndex, if you call either `df.index.get_level_values(0)` `df.index.get_level_values(1)`, you'll see that the index level returned has the same length as your DataFrame (with the elements repeated as necessary).

If you know that each index pairing will be a unique combination, as in your example, you can call:

```
df.index.get_level_values(0).nunique()
```

...with the either level of your MultiIndex as the argument (i.e. either `0` or `1`) and you'll get the number of individuals. If you will end up with combinations where the previous assumption will not hold true, you can try calling `df.index.nunique()`, though it may throw an error if you have duplicates in the index. The safest bet may instead be:

```
 d.index.value_counts().size
```

...which is a bit roundabout, but ensures that you get the number of unique combinations.

Comment: referring to the question above, I want to get the x, if you want. or the len(), of and y. In this particular example, it is 3.

Comment: Did you try either of the approaches I suggested? Both should return 3.